# PHP Apache sending large data through postman getting url not found error

Tags: php, apache, mod-fcgid

I have an API that is used to fetch the data from an external call. The problem is when I am trying to send almost 800 records JSON it shows URL not found but if I reduce the size to 300 it starts working. I have increased the memory limit, execution time,post_max size, etc but nothing is working.

One more thing is when I am trying to send large data from within the local network through postman it is working but when I am using public IP which is pointing to our private IP it shows URL not found with large data but with small data it also working.

One error which I am getting in the apache error log

```
 [fcgid:warn] [pid 5908:tid 1364] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : [client 172.16.100.100:44664] mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client
```

Comment: It could be that the client used to send the large data is not working properly. **More detail:** A client may need to send multiple times in parts when the send buffer in the operating system is full. So, if the client program is ignoring the *size sent* and that stuff, it is undefined behavior. Hence there is difference in behavior in local network and outside the local network.

Comment: Another thing could be that it is taking a long time, and the ISP has a timeout set.